# Install Latest Blender in Ubuntu-Studio

Tags: software-installation, updates, blender, official-repositories

I have recently installed Ubuntu-Studio. After install I executed the command:

sudo apt-get update

I also executed this menu item:

System => Software Updater

In spite of this I found the Blender installation I have, which is the one that comes with Ubuntu-Studio, is version 2.76b. But according to the Blender website:
https://www.blender.org/download/
the latest stable version is 2.77a. The web page does say this is a "release candidate". On the other hand there is no download on this page that seems to be an actual release and not a candidate release. And given that this web page shows version 2.78 to be the current test build, I have to conclude that 2.77a is the latest stable release. So what is the proper way to get Ubuntu-Studio to update to this latest stable release as given on that download webpage?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu repository may not have the latest versions. This is necessary to ensure the stability and security of the whole system.

**Don't worry**, there is a quick and common solution!

A *good* way to install a software is using the [source distribution](http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/) and every stable software should have a README\INSTALL file containing the appropriate instructions.

**But in the case of Blender** there is an alternative: just include an external repository and download a package in 3 commands.
[This procedure (click here)](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-the-latest-blender-release-ubuntu/) should be simpler and maintainable.

<sup>Have a nice day, feel free to comment under here if you need more help.</sup>

Comment: How often is the Ubuntu repository updated? I have looked at the [Thomas-Schiex repository](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender/) . What I see there for blender there is the latest test version 2.78. What I need is the latest stable version 2.77a.

Comment: @Stephen is updated very frequently, but you may experience a release delay of two weeks or more (bugs, legal licenses, ...); the PPA linked in the answer is updated every week and contains both the stable ("blender", you Should use this) and the very latest ("blender-edge") versions. If you need a very specific version, you may (and really should, for your security) compile it directly from source.

Comment: The latest Ubuntu release which is supported by [that ppa](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender) is groovy (20.10), for later releases the ppa does not have a release file and is not usable. See the [index of that ppa](https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu/dists/)

Answer (score 1):

For all recent versions of Ubuntu the Blender Foundation provides a [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/blender) with the most recent stable release. Installation is as easy as you can type

```
snap install blender
```

in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your app store (discover) and search for blender, you'll see the version installed on studio isn't an official release, you need to uninstall it and install the one released by the blender foundation to update it successfully.